# Proof that a certain set is open

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Supose $V$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n + k}$.

Define $T = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^k: (0, y) \in V \}$

Is $T$ open?

---

I think I can prove it as follows:

Define $g : \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n + k}$ as:

$g(y) = (0, y)$

$g$ is continous, so $T = g^{-1} (V)$ is open.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.